# Optimizing geom_point on top of expanded geom_raster background

Tags: r, ggplot2, neural-network

I'm trying to visualize how a neural network separates a simple 2 dimension points into 2 classes. I use `geom_point` to denote the training points and `geom_raster` to denote how the neural network separates the 2D space. Here's the functions and some of the data points plotted.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(neuralnet)

data2 <- structure(list(X1 = c(152, 178, 19, 101, 145, 184), x = c(32.4083268723916, 
84.5016641449183, 114.483315175202, 51.914560098842, 79.6402378017537, 
82.6861507166177), y = c(18.339864264708, 83.42093185056, 63.2843023451388, 
55.7215069333086, 42.6517407153766, 86.5805756277405), label = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("1", "2"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(152L, 
178L, 19L, 101L, 145L, 184L), class = "data.frame")

nn.model <- neuralnet(label~x+y, data2, hidden=4, linear.output=FALSE)

background <- expand_grid(x=seq(-40,120,0.1), y=seq(0,100,0.1))
background$label <- predict(nn.model, background) %>% apply(1, which.max)
ggplot()+geom_raster(data=background, aes(x, y, fill=label))+geom_point(data=data2, aes(x, y, color=label))+scale_color_manual(values=c("white","red"))
```

In the original dataset, the points lie in x range (-40, 120) and y range (0, 100); therefore the `background` expands accordingly. This approach, of course, takes some time because R will need to have the neural network predict some 1600 x 1000 points and then render them on the `geom_raster`  layer.

My question: is there way to optimize or do this another way in `ggplot` (or in another package, if this problem is solved well there), as this approach is brute force in `geom_raster`ing the background?

Comment: If the question is about ggplot and not about running neural networks, can you just post a sample of the predicted data instead? That would mean fewer packages for us to have setup and less for us to run

Comment: The neural network predicts the entire expanded grid, a sample of predictions would not be representative. Will it be better if I just put the `dput()` output for the entire expanded grid?

Comment: If it's not huge, maybe. I'm just guessing that if you're saying it takes a while to predict, it will be easier for folks here (and therefore more likely for you to get help) if we don't have to do that whole process and can just start from some amount of data that represents what you're trying to plot.